# Dynamic style listview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm generating a list view from an ajax call to a web-service.

This is the code:

```
var ajax = {  
parseJSONP:function(result){  
    movieInfo.result = result.results;
    $.each(result.results, function(i, row) {

        console.log("Title" + row.title);


        $('#movie-list').append('<li><a href="" data-id="' + row.id + '">`<img src="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w185'+row.poster_path+'"/>`<h3>' + row.title + '</h3><p>' + row.vote_average + '/10</p></a></li>');
    });

    $('#movie-list').listview('refresh');
}
```

};

What I need, is to make `<img src="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w185'+row.poster_path+'"/>`to fill the background of the row element and increase the row height by 30%. The problem is that I can't figure a way to insert the css with the list view creation.

Is there a way to do this? I'm new to javascript and jQuery mobile 1.4.3.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I notice:

- You are calling a jquery selector to get the element with the id of movie-list multiple times because the selector is in a loop. Rather than using jquery to look up the same element over and over again, you should set it into a variable and reuse it!
- You are creating html using string concatenation. While this is usually fine for small amounts of dynamic html, it can very quickly become difficult to maintain. I suggest creating the DOM elements and appending them to each other (without the use of jquery) instead of making a giant html string.
- You're building html in javascript! If at all possible, I would suggest adjusting your API to return the chunk of html that you need and build it server side rather than building it client side. If you build the html server side, then you can take advantage of whatever rendering framework you are using (PHP, Jade, JSF, etc...) and write the html as html.

With those things in mind, setting the background-image style property should work just fine. You may also need to use background-repeat and background-size to get the desired effect.

Here's what I came up with:

```
var ajax = {
    parseJSONP:function(response){
        var results = response.results;
        movieInfo.result = results;

        var $movieList = $("#movie-list");

        for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var row = results[i];

            console.log("Title: " + row.title);

            var listItem = document.createElement("li");
            var anchor = document.createElement("a");
            var header = document.createElement("h3");
            var paragraph = document.createElement("p");

            anchor.setAttribute("href", "");
            anchor.setAttribute("data-id", row.id);

            header.textContent = row.title;
            paragraph.textContent = row.vote_average + "/10";

            var backgroundImageUrl = "http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w185" + row.poster_path;
            listItem.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + backgroundImageUrl + "')";
            listItem.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
            listItem.style.backgroundSize = "cover";

            anchor.appendChild(header);
            anchor.appendChild(paragraph);
            listItem.appendChild(anchor);

            $movieList.append(listItem);
        }

        $movieList.listview('refresh');

        //increases the height of each list item by thirty percent
        $movieList.find("li").each(function(index, element) {
            var $element = $(element);
            $element.css("height", ($element.offset().height * 1.3) + "px");
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Excellent answer, clarified some doubts I had, just one litle problem, I'm working with your code and it just renders the table but with no info no images no text :(

Comment: I just adjusted it to use textContent instead of innerText. This makes firefox happy!

Comment: Still no image showing, here is a working example with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/claire89/6k4983s0/4/

Comment: It is because the anchor tag has a background color on it that is covering up the styling on the list item. If you style the anchor instead of the list item, then it works fine. Change `listItem` to `anchor` on line 73.

Comment: Thanks for all the help :) one small thing, the height of each row is not changing, do you know why?

Comment: Looks like where I am calling `$element.offset().height` I should have been using `$element.height()` (line 89 of the fiddle). It also seems like rather than just increasing the height of the li, we should actually be increasing the height of the anchor inside of it. Accordingly, change the selector on line 87 from `$("li")` to `$("li  a")`.

Answer (score 0):

Use html append like:

```
$('#movie-list').append('<li style="background:url(http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w185'+row.poster_path+') no-repeat; height:30%;"><a href="" data-id="' + row.id + '"><h3>' + row.title + '</h3><p>' + row.vote_average + '/10</p></a></li>');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but with your code the image disappeared :)